# Kombat Pack redeemed on the wrong account

Tags: xbox-one, mortal-kombat-x

My little brother who shares an Xbox One with me used our Kombat pack code on his silver account instead of my gold one. Now I can't see the upcoming DLC characters in the roster or use the samurai skins that came out. Does this mean I can't use the new characters without spending another $30?

Comment: Damn, that sucks.  You could try phoning Microsoft support and see if they could somehow adjust it for you, but otherwise I'm pretty sure you're out of luck.  Also don't let your little brother play Mortal Kombat.